# MongoDB create DB for tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, chai

Is there a way to create a proxy database for server(Node.js) tests (Mocha+ Chai). DB for development and production are created on MLab. But idea create one more DB especially for the tests seems to me not so good idea.

Comment: Creating a separate, dedicated DB especially for tests is an excellent idea.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Thilo's answer that having a dedicated DB for tests is a good idea, but you can also use something like [mongo-mock](https://github.com/williamkapke/mongo-mock) for this, which is an in-memory MongoDB instance you can use for tests.